# Connect Samsung Galaxy S2 with laptop. thru WIFI Direct

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, android

How can I send a picture from the phone to the laptop.

Bluetooth is the easiest way, but not so fast.
I want to use WIFI direct, but I cant find the laptop when i'm searching. 
What do I need to do to get a connection?

Comment: The simplest way would be to either email yourself the picture and/or connect the phone using the usb cable that came with the phone.

Answer (score 3):

Samsung KIES or AirDroid (from Android Market) does the job well. Files can be transferred over wifi by using your web browser.

AirDroid gives a quick and painless way to transfer files

Answer (score 1):

I like [Sweet Home](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sweesoft.sweethome)
but it works through my home router, not direct to the computer

Answer (score 1):

I looked for this myself but I'm pretty sure Wifi direct only works with other Wifi direct devices, not your average PC Wireless router. You'll have to just plug in the USB cable like a caveman.

Answer (score 1):

I use [WiFi File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&hl=en). Works very well for wireless file transfers.
(I use the free version, but there is space limits on the free one so you can't transfer large files. The paid version AFAIK has no space limit)